# physicsBody applyForce does nothing

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm doing this video tutorial:
http://www.spritebuilder.com/getting-started/

Everything works fine but the birds im shooting have no speed. They just fall down.

Hope you guys have a solution! Thanks in advance!

Here is my lauchBird function:

```
-(void)launchBird:(id)sender
{

//calc rotation
float rotationRadians = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(_launcher.rotation);


//vector for rotation
CGPoint directionVector = ccp(sinf(rotationRadians), cosf(rotationRadians));

CGPoint ballOffset = ccpMult(directionVector, 50);

//ball (bird)
CCNode* ball = [CCBReader load:@"Bird"];
ball.position = ccpAdd(_launcher.position, ballOffset);


//add ball to physicsNode
[_physicsNode addChild:ball];


//make impulse and apply force
CGPoint force = ccpMult(directionVector, 50000);
[ball.physicsBody applyForce:force];

}
```

Comment: Is the ball's physicsBody nil?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just checked, it's nil indeed! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Allen S, you need to add a physicsBody to the ball. You can do this by

```
int padding = 5;
CGFloat radius = 0.5*(ball.contentSize.width - padding);

//create a physics body

CCPhysicsBody* body = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:radius andCenter:ball.anchorPointInPoints];
body.density = 1.0;
body.friction = 0.5f;
ball.physicsBody = body; //assign the created body to the node's physicsBody property.
```

Play around with the physicsBody's properties(density,friction,mass,elasticity...) to get the desired effect.